# Regular expression to get text between <br>

Tags: regex

I have a string that contains this (and another things):

```
the text<br> 
Text text text and mooore text...<br> 
Text text text and mooore text...<br>
Text text text and mooore text...<br>
```

I need a reg-ex to get the text between `<br>` tags and first text.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1051677 yet another one who thinks that RegExp will help with html parsing ...

Comment: @Author, Rephrase your question, what is problem statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want this:

```
the text<br>\nText text text and mooore text...<br> 
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Regex: **`(?:<br>)([\s\S]*?)(?=<br>)`**

1. `(?:<br>)` --> Ensure a `<br>` is there (do not match it)
2. `([\s\S]*?)` --> Match everything lazily and capture it.
3. `(?=<br>)` --> Ensure a `<br>` follows.

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uU2qP3)

P.S. As others have said, you cannot parse HTML tags as [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).